# how do I stop the screen reader from reading the navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, accessibility

for example in ios when I navigate from one page to another the URLs in nav bar are like this:

```
www.myweburl/module/id => www.myweburl/module/34hjasdsadasd4234
```

Instantly the screen reader reads the URL

Obviously, I want to prevent the screen reader from reading the id ("`34hjasdsadasd4234`"), and obviously, the id must be in the URL.

Is there any strategy or something that can be done in this case?

Comment: Voice Over is reading the new URL as soon as the new page loads? Does that page have a title?

Comment: Titles are certainly important but the user can still navigate to the address bar and hear the URL  It sounds like the OP wants to prevent the URL of the page from being read, which is not possible (nor desirable).  Sighted users can **see** the URL so why should a screen reader user not be able to **hear** the URL?

Comment: That’s what I’m wondering why @yavgz would like to change that. But they state that the URL was read as soon as the page loads. Isn’t focus leaving the address bar when the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

No. Address and navigation bar is part of the UI of the browser, which you fortunately don't have any control on.

IF you need to hide numeric IDs for security reasons, you must change URLs in such a way that numeric IDs don't appear at all, by replacing them by something impossible to guess.
Universally unique identifiers (UUID) are known to do that pretty well.